# constructing a POST request

Tags: python-requests, http-post

below link gives scanned list of stocks based on certain conditions

https://chartink.com/screener/mwdbscans

i can see that below is the url i should use for POST request

https://chartink.com/screener/process

i am facing problem when i want to send a POST request to get the list in python
from the developer tools, i could see the request headers and form data but when i encode the data and send the POST request i get error 500 (internal server error)

the data body of POST request i tried is,

```
Host: chartink.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0)   
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://chartink.com/screener/nsk-ohl-long
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-CSRF-TOKEN: PsJC0BUBkL7gE8YyglD6uYU8TpjqXLvN3whpdM9v
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 179
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1391629072.1532845865; XSRF-                                                    
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: can you put data what you trying here and please mention the data type expect from server side

Comment: https://chartink.com/screener/nsk-ohl-long 
please open this link. above POST requests expect list of stocks scanned as per conditions along with a link to download excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

This is because mismatch of send data and the server side deserialize. you should send  data from correct form to the server side. then server will be able to deserialise your data correctly.

Comment: i understand that this is what is required to be done. but i dont know how to do it!